# Get total number of records for a given day in Highcharts and PHP

Tags: php, highcharts

I'm trying to get my highcharts chart working and I'm almost there.. I just have one little problem: I need that the value will be the total count of the records at the same day but I'm kinda confused with my code now and the chart is totally messed up..

Here is the code that pulls the data:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");

include('../includes/config.php');

$tablename = "analytics";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM $tablename");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

$sql = "SELECT id, date FROM $tablename ORDER BY date";
$result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error());

$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row['id'] = (int) $row['id'];

    $rows[$i] = array(strtotime($row['date'])*1000, $row['id']);

    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

If it will help here is my database values:

```
insert  into `analytics`(`id`,`user`,`item`,`ip`,`country`,`date`) values
(10,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:41:51'),
(11,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:42:23'),
(12,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:43:07'),
(13,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:44:19'),
(14,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:44:21'),
(15,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:44:22'),
(16,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:44:49'),
(17,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:46:59'),
(18,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:47:20'),
(19,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:47:35'),
(20,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:47:42'),
(21,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:48:07'),
(22,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:48:14'),
(23,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 06:48:29'),
(24,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-18 06:49:10'),
(25,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-19 07:05:45'),
(26,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-20 08:11:32'),
(27,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-21 08:26:45'),
(28,1,1,'127.0.0.1','','2011-12-17 08:44:34');
```

And here is the final result:
[image: result]

I totally lost my self here, can someone help?

EDIT: did what @ajreal said and here is the output:
[image: result2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query to get count for each date

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM $tablename
GROUP BY date;
```

You can use this query to replace your first query.
And to a loop (like your second query), set `$total += $row["count"]` to get a grand total like your original first query does

Comment: well i've did what you said and there its a bit better now but still.. please see my EDIT.

Comment: OK, I've fixed it with the following change to the query: `SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM $tablename
GROU BY date(date)`